# Fitting a model using formula and Negative binomial in statsmodels 0.6

Tags: python, statsmodels

I`m trying to analyze a dataset with Negative Binomial in the statsmodels 0.6 module with python 3.4.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.api as sm
model2=smf.glm("an_darlingi ~ trat", data=dados,
             family=sm.families.NegativeBinomial()).fit()
```

which outputs:

```
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:            an_darlingi   No. Observations:                  363
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                      352
Model Family:        NegativeBinomial   Df Model:                           10
Link Function:                    log   Scale:                   1.52662855632
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -1404.7
Date:                Mon, 13 Oct 2014   Deviance:                       578.37
Time:                        19:34:45   Pearson chi2:                     537.
No. Iterations:                     7                                         
=================================================================================
                    coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept         2.9988      0.220     13.607      0.000         2.567     3.431
trat[T.CO2]      -0.3070      0.313     -0.981      0.327        -0.920     0.306
trat[T.ML]       -0.1709      0.312     -0.547      0.584        -0.783     0.441
trat[T.SFPF]     -0.3215      0.313     -1.027      0.304        -0.935     0.292
trat[T.SFPM]     -0.4085      0.314     -1.303      0.193        -1.023     0.206
trat[T.SFTF]     -0.0448      0.312     -0.144      0.886        -0.656     0.566
trat[T.SFTM]     -0.1835      0.312     -0.587      0.557        -0.796     0.429
trat[T.SIPF]     -0.3905      0.313     -1.246      0.213        -1.005     0.224
trat[T.SIPM]     -0.1799      0.312     -0.576      0.565        -0.792     0.432
trat[T.SIPTM]     0.0700      0.311      0.225      0.822        -0.540     0.680
trat[T.SITF]      0.1968      0.311      0.633      0.527        -0.413     0.806
=================================================================================
```

In the output I got values of t and p and I like to get values of z and P>(z) like in R. How can I do this using smf.glm instead sm.NegativeBinomial. Because if I try to use sm.NegativeBinomial I got error msg sayng that cant convert string SIPTM to a float.

Comment: Which version of statsmodels are you using? Can you check whether the values are for t and P>|t| are not the same as in R? The labels might be wrong. (In the current development version of statsmodels it is z values, i.e. based on normal distribution, and there is an option to choose whether to use t or normal.)

Comment: I'm using the version 0.5. The values are not the same in R so I think that in this case statmodels it's using t. Is there the same option for the version 0.5 or I have to change to

Comment: There is no option for switching between t/F and normal/chisquare distribution for inference in version 0.5 or older.

Comment: Ty so much... I'll change my statmodels version